# return value is not rendering when returned from inside the handleclick() function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './home.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
class ChangeButton extends React.Component {
 /* In this I want that when link one is click button corresponding to that 
  link should appear */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrayofval:[]
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
             arrayofval:[{label:'a',value:'ab'},
                {label:'b',value:'bb'},
                {label:'c',value:'cb'},
                {label:'d',value:'db'},
                {label:'e',value:'eb'}
            ]
        })
    }
    handleClick(index){
        if(index===0){
          /* this button should appear if the first link is clicked*/
            console.log("Come here if first link is clicked ")
            return (<div>
                        <button className="button1">
                            Connect1
                        </button>
                    </div>);
        }
        else if(index===1)
        {
                    console.log("Come here if second link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                        <button className="button1">
                            Connect 2
                        </button>
                    </div>

        }
        else if(index===2){
            console.log("Come here if 3rd link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <button className="button1">
                    Connect 3
                </button>
            </div>

        }
        else if(index===3){
            console.log("Come here if 4th link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <div className="button1">
                    Connect 4
                </div>
            </div>

        }
        else{
            console.log("Come here if 5th link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <button className="button1">
                    Connect 5
                </button>
            </div>

        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        <li className="list-group-item">
<a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(0)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[0].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[1].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[2].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[3].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[4].label}</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ChangeButton />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

This is the code for displaying button according to the link clicked, so if link one is clicked the button with connect1 should be rendered.I am getting the link and when I am clicking on the link function is calling correct value also but the button is not coming.Suppose I click on the first link I got the console message for that but button has not appeared on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return values from event listeners don't render anything. The only time something is rendered is in the `render` function. Event listeners happen in response to some event, not during the render process.

The way to handle this is would be to have your event listener set some state, and then render based on that:

```
handleClick(index) {
  this.setState({
    clicked: index
  });
}
```

--

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <ul className="list-group">
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(0)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[0].label}</a>
          </li>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[1].label}</a>
          </li>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[2].label}</a>
          </li>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[3].label}</a>
          </li>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[4].label}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <button className="button1">
            Connect {this.state.clicked + 1}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

An even better way would be to use `.map` on your array:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.state.arrayofval.map((item, i) => (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={i}>
              <a onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} href="#">{item.label}</a>
              {this.state.clicked === i &&
                <button className="button1">
                  Connect {this.state.clicked + 1}
                </button>
              }
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen something like a click event returns a component.
You must think different way for best practises and use **state** I think.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './home.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
class ChangeButton extends React.Component {
 /* In this I want that when link one is click button corresponding to that 
  link should appear */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrayofval:[],
            clicked: -1
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
             arrayofval:[{label:'a',value:'ab'},
                {label:'b',value:'bb'},
                {label:'c',value:'cb'},
                {label:'d',value:'db'},
                {label:'e',value:'eb'}
            ]
        })
    }
    handleClick(index){
      this.setState({clicked: index});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                          <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(0)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[0].label}</a>
                          { this.state.clicked === 0 ? <button className="button1">Connect1</button> : null }
                        </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                          <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[1].label}</a>
                          { this.state.clicked === 1 ? <button className="button1">Connect2</button> : null }
                        </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                          <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[2].label}</a>
                          { this.state.clicked === 2 ? <button className="button1">Connect3</button> : null }
                        </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                          <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[3].label}</a>
                          { this.state.clicked === 3 ? <button className="button1">Connect4</button> : null }
                        </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                          <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[4].label}</a>
                          { this.state.clicked === 4 ? <button className="button1">Connect5</button> : null }
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ChangeButton />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to change state whenever the `handleClick()` method is called:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './home.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
class ChangeButton extends React.Component {
 /* In this I want that when link one is click button corresponding to that 
  link should appear */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrayofval:[]
            index: 0 // this is where I track state change
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
             arrayofval:[{label:'a',value:'ab'},
                {label:'b',value:'bb'},
                {label:'c',value:'cb'},
                {label:'d',value:'db'},
                {label:'e',value:'eb'}
            ]
        })
    }
    handleClick(index){
        if(index===0){
          /* this button should appear if the first link is clicked*/
            console.log("Come here if first link is clicked ")
            return (<div>
                        <button className="button1">
                            Connect1
                        </button>
                    </div>);
// set the index value in any of these conditions
        }
        else if(index===1)
        {
                    console.log("Come here if second link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                        <button className="button1">
                            Connect 2
                        </button>
                    </div>

        }
        else if(index===2){
            console.log("Come here if 3rd link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <button className="button1">
                    Connect 3
                </button>
            </div>

        }
        else if(index===3){
            console.log("Come here if 4th link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <div className="button1">
                    Connect 4
                </div>
            </div>

        }
        else{
            console.log("Come here if 5th link is clicked ")
            return <div>
                <button className="button1">
                    Connect 5
                </button>
            </div>

        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        <li className="list-group-item">
<a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(0)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[0].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(1)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[1].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(2)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[2].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(3)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[3].label}</a> </li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(4)} href="#">{this.state.arrayofval[4].label}</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ChangeButton />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Calling `setState()` allows the component to re-render.